# Cálculo errado com While

Tags: c, algoritmo

Nesse exercício é para digitar dois números e imprimir na tela eles mesmos, e os inteiros entre eles. Porém, se eu digito por exemplo 10 e 20, o último número que aparece é 19 ao invés de 20; e se eu digito 20 e 10, o último número aparece 11.

O meu erro não está nos `if`s pelo o que eu testei, posso estar errado.

OBS: preciso usar o while.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n1, n2;

main()
{
    printf("Para saber os inteiros entre dois numeros siga os passos abaixo: \n");
    printf("Digite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    system("cls");
    if((n1 == n2)||(n2 == n1)){
            printf("NUMEROS IGUAIS!\n");
    }
    while((n1 < n2)||(n1 > n2))
    {
         if(n1 < n2){
            printf("%d\n", n1);
            n1 = n1 + 1;
        }else if(n1 > n2){
            printf("%d\n", n1);
            n1 = n1 - 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Precisa definir melhor o problema, se é para imprimir os número entre eles é para imprimir de 11 à 19.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, acho que ficou mais claro agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema principal é que está mandando parar quando é maior ou é menor, mas você quer que inclua o valor dentro do limite, então tem que aceitar quando o valor é igual ao limite também portanto precisaria usa\r `<=` e `>=` no `while`.

Esse código é complexo demais e ineficiente por fazer várias operações sem necessidade alguma (3 *branches* em cada passo contra 1 do meu). Então eu acho melhor fazer assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n1, n2;
    printf("Para saber os inteiros entre dois numeros siga os passos abaixo: \n");
    printf("Digite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    if (n1 == n2) printf("NUMEROS IGUAIS!\n");
    else if (n1 < n2) while (n1 <= n2) printf("%d\n", n1++);
    else while (n1 >= n2) printf("%d\n", n1--);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/L17NvK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Intervalc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Interval.c).

Comment: É que nesse exercício precisaria usar o while (a professora pediu).. eu tentei colocar como você falou <= e >= dentro do while, porém agora o código ficou rodando infinitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Use o operador **<=** na suas condições, tipo:

```
do {
     if(n1 <= n2){
       printf("%d\n", n1);
       n1 = n1 + 1;
     } else {
       printf("%d\n", n1);
       n1 = n1 - 1;
     }
 } while((n1 <= n2)||(n1 => n2));
```

Comment: Pior que o resultado continua dando o mesmo que comentei ali em cima.. eu estou achando que tem alguma coisa errada na condição que eu coloquei no while.. mas não estou conseguindo achar o problema.

Comment: Tenta usar o Do While, editei o código acima, fiz  aqui com javascript e rodou certo aqui.